# how to find out labels which are detected using touch or gesture in ios.?

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer

I am developing a college project on game in iPhone which is based on finding words in grid view of labels..
I have to find out labels(actually they are alphabets) which are detected while draging finger.
can anyone help me to know what controls that i can use to find appropriate labels detected while dragging..

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: What gesture do you need? Is the user going to tap the labels?

Answer (score 1):

You can get your label using this.

**NOTE** You have to set `userinteractionEnabled = YES` for all your `UILabel`

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        UILabel *label=(UILabel*)touch.view;
        NSLog(@"%@",label.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: hey @Rajneesh071 i think your answer some like my answer.. see

Comment: @ParasJoshi  userinteractionEnabled things made it quite right, it will certainly work. +1.

Comment: Here that user define that he can drag that UILabel and its possible when its `userinteractionEnabled` is `YES` so i not Define that.. :)

Comment: @ParasJoshi - if you drag drop UILabel then by default its userinteractionEnabled is NO..

Comment: @ParasJoshi and its not like your answer.. its like objective c coding :P

Comment: what i say bro that user can drag and drop uilable on the UIView at run time he defined that read quetion...

Answer (score 0):

```
//To know exact Label from grid of Label use Tag property of tag


//To drag selected Label
//use this code

    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:Label] anyObject];

        // get delta
        CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:Label];
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:Label];
        CGFloat delta_x = location.x - previousLocation.x;
        CGFloat delta_y = location.y - previousLocation.y;

        // move button
        Label.center = CGPointMake(Label.center.x + delta_x,
            Label.center.y + delta_y);
//Alphabet on label
NSString *alphabet = Label.text;
```